# Cannot Initialize Cassandra on macOS

Tags: java, macos, cassandra

I have installed Cassandra 3.11.3 on macOS 10.14.
openjdk version "11" 2018-09-25
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11+28)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11+28, mixed mode)

When I attempt to start cassandra, I get

```
    INFO  [main] 2018-10-26 15:11:28,607 ColumnFamilyStore.java:411 - Initializing system_schema.aggregates
INFO  [main] 2018-10-26 15:11:28,613 ColumnFamilyStore.java:411 - Initializing system_schema.indexes
INFO  [main] 2018-10-26 15:11:28,615 ViewManager.java:137 - Not submitting build tasks for views in keyspace system_schema as storage service is not initialized
Exception (java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError) encountered during startup: null
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ObjectSizes.sizeOfReferenceArray(ObjectSizes.java:79)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ObjectSizes.sizeOfArray(ObjectSizes.java:89)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ObjectSizes.sizeOnHeapExcludingData(ObjectSizes.java:112)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.AbstractBufferClusteringPrefix.unsharedHeapSizeExcludingData(AbstractBufferClusteringPrefix.java:70)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.BTreeRow.unsharedHeapSizeExcludingData(BTreeRow.java:440)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.AtomicBTreePartition$RowUpdater.apply(AtomicBTreePartition.java:336)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.AtomicBTreePartition$RowUpdater.apply(AtomicBTreePartition.java:295)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.btree.BTree.buildInternal(BTree.java:139)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.btree.BTree.build(BTree.java:121)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.btree.BTree.update(BTree.java:178)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.AtomicBTreePartition.addAllWithSizeDelta(AtomicBTreePartition.java:156)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable.put(Memtable.java:282)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.apply(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1335)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.applyInternal(Keyspace.java:626)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.apply(Keyspace.java:470)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Mutation.apply(Mutation.java:227)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Mutation.apply(Mutation.java:232)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Mutation.apply(Mutation.java:241)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.ModificationStatement.executeInternalWithoutCondition(ModificationStatement.java:587)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.ModificationStatement.executeInternal(ModificationStatement.java:581)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.executeOnceInternal(QueryProcessor.java:363)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.persistLocalMetadata(SystemKeyspace.java:520)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:221)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:602)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:691)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end -1, length 5
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3319)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1874)
    at org.github.jamm.MemoryLayoutSpecification.getEffectiveMemoryLayoutSpecification(MemoryLayoutSpecification.java:190)
    at org.github.jamm.MemoryLayoutSpecification.<clinit>(MemoryLayoutSpecification.java:31)
    ... 25 more
ERROR [main] 2018-10-26 15:11:28,682 CassandraDaemon.java:708 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ObjectSizes.sizeOfReferenceArray(ObjectSizes.java:79) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ObjectSizes.sizeOfArray(ObjectSizes.java:89) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ObjectSizes.sizeOnHeapExcludingData(ObjectSizes.java:112) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.AbstractBufferClusteringPrefix.unsharedHeapSizeExcludingData(AbstractBufferClusteringPrefix.java:70) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.BTreeRow.unsharedHeapSizeExcludingData(BTreeRow.java:440) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.AtomicBTreePartition$RowUpdater.apply(AtomicBTreePartition.java:336) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.AtomicBTreePartition$RowUpdater.apply(AtomicBTreePartition.java:295) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.btree.BTree.buildInternal(BTree.java:139) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.btree.BTree.build(BTree.java:121) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.btree.BTree.update(BTree.java:178) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.AtomicBTreePartition.addAllWithSizeDelta(AtomicBTreePartition.java:156) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable.put(Memtable.java:282) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.apply(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1335) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.applyInternal(Keyspace.java:626) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.apply(Keyspace.java:470) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Mutation.apply(Mutation.java:227) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Mutation.apply(Mutation.java:232) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Mutation.apply(Mutation.java:241) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.ModificationStatement.executeInternalWithoutCondition(ModificationStatement.java:587) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.ModificationStatement.executeInternal(ModificationStatement.java:581) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.executeOnceInternal(QueryProcessor.java:363) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.persistLocalMetadata(SystemKeyspace.java:520) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:221) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:602) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:691) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end -1, length 5
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3319) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1874) ~[na:na]
    at org.github.jamm.MemoryLayoutSpecification.getEffectiveMemoryLayoutSpecification(MemoryLayoutSpecification.java:190) ~[jamm-0.3.0.jar:na]
    at org.github.jamm.MemoryLayoutSpecification.<clinit>(MemoryLayoutSpecification.java:31) ~[jamm-0.3.0.jar:na]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

I am guessing, something is not initialised somewhere or there is a Java-related incompatibility. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Ended up downgrading Java to 1.8.0_191. This works.

Answer (score 3):

Support for Java > 8 will be only in the Cassandra 4.0, and the planned release date isn't known yet. So you always need to use Java 8 for Casasndra 3.11.x

You can read more about upcoming version and Java 11 in following [blog post](http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2018/08/16/java11.html).